# How to change font size while scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I'm searching a way to change font size while user is scrolling. I want to synchronize it with the scrolling position, so that the font size is decreasing with animation while user is scrolling down, and the font size is increasing with animation while user is scrolling up.

Does anybody know how to do this with Javascript?

Comment: $(document).scroll(function(){ $("font").css("size",size"); });

Comment: Thanks everybody for the help, especially @aa-shakil. I have found the solution:

'jQuery(document).scroll(function () {
 var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
 var scroll2 = 100 - (scroll/2);
 
 if (scroll2 >= 50) {
    jQuery(".naslovna").css({
            'font-size': scroll2 + 'px'
        });
    }
});'

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the jQuery library and it’s built in `.scroll()` and `.css()` elements.

However, you’re going to need to look up how to use these elements and at least **attempt** to implement this code.

After you’ve made an attempt and still can’t grasp it, come back with your full html, css, and jS and then maybe you’ll be eligible for assistance.

Comment: Sorry, it was my first time posting the question, and after whole day of figuring out how to do it, I compose this low quality question. I understand your reply.

This is the code I have for now: 

`code`jQuery(document).scroll(function () {
 var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    jQuery(".naslovna").css({
            'font-size': scroll + 'px'
        });
    
});
`code`

I have to figure now how to start decrease from original size.

Answer (score 0):

**You can** , by using **`mouse wheel`** **event** in jQuery **like**:

**jsfiddle** [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ar4ct9ab/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.content-wrap').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
     var current = parseInt($(this).css('font-size'));
        if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
            $('.content-wrap').css("font-size" , (current +1) +"px");
        }
        else{  
            $('.content-wrap').css("font-size" , (current - 1)+"px");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.content-wrap {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-wrap">
         hello world
    <br/>hello world
    <br/>hello world
    <br/>hello world
</div>
```